# NLog doesn't roll over on file size

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have the following defined for testing to see if the specified log files roll over but I never see it happening. Any ideas?

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${message}" 
        filename="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/logs/configlog.log" 
        archiveFileName="configlog.{##}.log" archiveAboveSize="5" archiveNumbering="Rolling" concurrentWrites="True" maxArchiveFiles="50" 
        keepFileOpen="True" encoding="iso-8859-2" enableFileDelete="False"></target>
```

Comment: Please can you tell us what you see at the moment within your log folder?

Comment: The original file configlog.log is there and I can see it growing to > megabyte in size but it's not rolling over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also include the path in your archiveFileName, so something like this will work:

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File" layout="${message}" 
    filename="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/logs/configlog.log"
    archiveFileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/logs/archive/configlog.{##}.log" archiveAboveSize="5" archiveNumbering="Rolling" concurrentWrites="True" maxArchiveFiles="50" 
    keepFileOpen="True" encoding="iso-8859-2" enableFileDelete="False"></target>
```

Also:
The archiveAboveSize parameter is in bytes, not megabytes. 
At the moment you telling nlog to roll over after 5 bytes, which might be causing issues.

Comment: you were not defining a path in the archiveFileName, i edited the answer to reflect this

Comment: Yeah thanks. That's what I realized. The issue I'm trying to fix is to lot try logging in the damn program files folder. ;)